# typescript use literals | string gives type as string

Tags: typescript, types

I'm writing a library, I have an object which I want to let the users of this library to get autocompletion on one of its properties, however I want them to be able to add other string too, my type is :

```
type Object2 = {
    prop: "*" | "line" | "media" | string;
}
```

On my IDE (Intellij) and also compile output I get :

```
Object2: {
    prop: string;
};
```

What I need to get however is the same as I defined `"*" | "line" | "media" | string` so what do I do I'm really stuck here

Comment: That's as design, they are all strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All string literal types get absorbed into `string`, because `string` is the base type of those literal types.

There is a way to prevent this, but intersecting `string` with `{}`

```
type Object2 = {
    prop: "*" | "line" | "media" | (string & {});
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AJigXigbwFBSFRgBOA9mAFxQBEAVDVAD60A2AlgHYSMs0C2EACbsAhrygAKAM7ASXAOZQAZLgC+ASgDceNUA)

Any string will still be assignable to the prop, but you will get suggestions in VS Code.

This is discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729). The `&{}` solution is also suggested there.

Comment: You can also add the open issue about it on GH : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729